# Delete highlight and place only replaced string in LiveCode

Tags: livecode

The following livecode for replace the particular text and highlight the both search and replace string. The search string also strike with help of html code. Now i try to add new button that perform delete the search string and place only the replaced string and that do not highlight.

```
 on mouseUp 
 put the htmlText of field "MytextField" into myHtml 
 set the caseSensitive to true
 put the field SRText into myArrayToBe
 split myArrayToBe by CR
 put the number of lines of (the keys of myArrayToBe) into myArraylength
  repeat with i = 1 to myArraylength 
  put  myArrayToBe[i] into y
  split y by colon
  put y[1] into searchStr
  put y[2] into replaceStr
  if searchStr is empty then
  put the  0 into m
  else 
  replace searchStr with  "<strike><font bgcolor=" & quote & "yellow" & quote & ">" & searchStr & "</font></strike><font bgcolor=" & quote & "green" & quote & ">" & replaceStr & "</font>" in myHtmlend if
  end repeat 
  set the htmlText of fld "MytextField" to myHtml 
end mouseUp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot test your code because I do not have your field contents. But know that the command "replace" requires a container from which the strings may be referenced:

replace searchString with replaceString in fld 1

It will not throw an error, but you do not need to use "the" in such circumstances as:

put the 0 into m (just say "put 0 into m)

put the field SRText into MyArrayToBe (put field SRText into...)
You get the picture.

Anyway, write back with some test text that we might evaluate, or better, make that test yourself with simple text. Then when that works, try it on your real text.

Craig Newman